# Constraints on fitting parameters with Python and ODRPACK

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

I'm using the ODRPACK library in Python to fit some 1d data. It works quite well, but I have one question: is there any possibility to make constraints on the fitting parameters? For example if I have a model y = a * x + b and for physical reasons parameter a can by only in range (-1, 1). I've found that such constraints can be done in original Fortran implementation of the ODRPACK95 library, but I can't find how to do that in Python.

Of course, I can implement my functions such that they will return very big values, if the fitting parameters are out of bounds and chi squared will be big too, but I wonder if there is a right way to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid that the older FORTRAN-77 version of ODRPACK wrapped by `scipy.odr` does not incorporate constraints. ODRPACK95 is a later extension of the original ODRPACK library that predates the `scipy.odr` wrappers, and it is unclear that we could legally include it in scipy. There is no explicit licensing information for ODRPACK95, only the general ACM TOMS non-commercial license.