# A Python module that can perform fitting with asymmetrical X and Y errors, and introduce bounds on fitted parameters?

Tags: python, scipy, model-fitting, lmfit

I am fitting datasets with some broken powerlaws, the data has assymetrical errors in X and Y, and I'd like to be able to introduce constrains on the fitted parameters (i.e. not below 0, or within a certain range).

Using Scipy.ODR, I can fit the data great including the assymetrical errors on both axes, however I can't seem to find any way in the documentation to introduce bounds on my fitted parameters and discussions online seem to suggest this is flat out impossible with this module: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17786438/19086741

Using Lmfit, I can also fit the data well and can introduce bounds to the fitted parameters. However, discussions online once again state that Lmfit is not able to handle asymmetrical errors, and errors on both axes.

Is there some module, or perhaps I am missing something with one of these modules, that would allow me to meet both of my requirements in this case? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have a good answer for you.  As you note, Lmfit does not support ODR regression which allows for uncertainties in the (single) independent variable as well as uncertainties in the dependent variables.
I think this would be possible in principle. Unfortunately, ODR has a very different interface to the other minimization routines making a wrapper as "another possible solving algorithm for lmfit" a bit challenging.   I am sure that none of the developers would object to someone trying this, but it would take some effort.

FWIW, you say "both axes" as if you are certain there are exactly 2 axes.  ODR supports exactly 1 independent variable: `lmfit` is not limited to this assumption.

You also say that lmfit cannot handle asymmetric uncertainties.  That is only partially true.  The `lmfit.Model` interface allows only a single uncertainty value per data point.  But with the `lmfit.minimize` interface, you write your own objective function to calculate the array you want minimized, and so can weight some residual of "data" and "model" any way you want.